# Converting boost::function to std::function

Tags: c++, boost, stl, c++11, std-function

I'm updating some of our old code to use C++11 features in place of boost equivalents. However not everything is a simple namespace replacement like unordered containers and smart pointers.

For example `boost::function` has methods `empty()` and `clear()` but `std::function` does not.

There is an `operator()` defined for `std::function` that I've been using to replace `empty()` references but what should I use to replace `clear()` references?

I've considered using the `std::function` assignment operator and assigning `nullptr` to clear it but I'm worried that might have unintentional side affects of clearing not only the underlying function but rendering the object unusable.

Obviously, the better solution would be default initialization of any reusable member function objects that way there is always a valid callback which can simply be updated with a user provided one but I'm just aiming for a direct replacement of the previous usage right now not a code review.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> There is an `operator()` defined for `std::function` that I've been using to replace `empty()`

Do you mean an `operator!` ?

For `empty` use that operator to test it in a boolean context:

```
if (f.empty())
```

becomes:

```
if (!f)
```

Or

```
if (!f.empty())
```

becomes:

```
if (f)
```

(That also works with `boost::function`, which also has `operator!` and `operator bool`.)

For `clear` assign `nullptr` to it, which doesn't render it unusable, it just sets it to a default-constructed state:

```
f.clear();
```

becomes

```
f = nullptr;
```

Or (thanks to Paul Groke for the suggestion):

```
f = {};
```

That's equivalent to:

```
f = decltype(f){};
```

but is more efficient, and much easier to type and easier to read!

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I worded it that way because the code is riddled with `if (!m_func.empty())` checks which I've been changing to `if (m_func)` ...

Comment: `f = {};` also works for resetting and I find it to be very elegant. Not sure though if it incurs a runtime overhead compared to `f = nullptr;`.

Comment: @PaulGroke, yes, that's elegant, and compiles to exactly the same as `f = nullptr`.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Looking at boost::function::clear() (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/boost/function/function_template.hpp) it does more than setting to nullptr, it also possible does a `get_vtable()->clear()`. So is `f = nullptr` really equivalent?

Comment: @jpo38 but how is that different to `std::function::operator=(nullptr_t)`? What do you think that function does?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: It's hard to say, as there is no more `get_vtable` function in std::function. Maybe it's equivalent, I was just asking.

Comment: @jpo38 it's equivalent. It "does more than setting to nullptr" as you put it. It does the same thing as `clear()`. That's why it's the answer ;-)